# angularjs filter multiple fields with OR Condition

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do a search field  filter using angular filter  for specific fields and which should be an `OR` condition

This is demo implementation http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/ck19wvdx/2/.
I'm trying to search only on `Name` and `Gender` but not  `Location`.

Whatever combination i tried it works more like `AND` condition.  Is there an inbuilt way to do `OR condition` in `filter`?

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<input type="text" ng-model="search">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users |  filter: search">{{user.Name}} | {{user.Location}}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>





var data = [
        {
            Name: "John Smith",
            Gender: "M",
            Location: "Wales"
        },
        {
            Name: "Sally Smith",
            Gender: "F",
            Location: "USA"
        },
        {
            Name: "Curtis Timson",
            Gender: "M",
            Location: "England"
        },
        {
            Name: "Sam Wallace",
            Gender: "M",
            Location: "England"
        },
        {
            Name: "Caroline James",
            Gender: "F",
            Location: "Scotland"
        }
    ];

    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
        $scope.users = data;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use a filter function instead of directly passing the search string to the filter. The relevant code is below. [**Here is ur fiddle modified.**](https://jsfiddle.net/vo708ecz/1/)

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users |  filter: filter">

$scope.filter = function(item) {
 var regex = new RegExp($scope.search, 'gi');
 return item.Name.match(regex) || item.Gender.match(regex); 
};
```

Comment: Nice and easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your demonstration works like an `OR` operator to me.

For example if i write `sa` in the input, the result is :

```
Sally Smith | USA
Sam Wallace | England
```

With a `AND`, `Sam Wallace | England` will be hidden because `England` contains no `sa`.

Comment: I want to exclude search for  Location field